# What does javascript document.createElement('bootstrap') do? There's no such DOM element type as 'bootstrap'!

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I'm trying to understand, how bootstrap transitions work.

In the beginning of [`transition.js` module](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/transition.js#L17) I found a statement, which I can't understand:

```
 var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')
```

How this is supposed to work? There's no `bootstrap` element in DOM, I believe.

Comment: you can use any name for elements in html5, and old browsers will just treat them as `div`s, there's nothing special about it being called `bootstrap`

Comment: @DavidFregoli so HTML5 is essentially XML now (with arbitrary attributes allowed as well)? Thanks. I can remove this question, or I can accept your answer, if you post it as an answer.

Comment: Those element are [MDN: HTMLUnknownElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement) , [WHATWG: HTMLUnknownElement](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#htmlunknownelement) without any special properties or methods. And not HTML5 is not XML, it does not enforce the strictness XML has. Technically `bootstrap` is also not ok as in HTML5 custom elements should contain a `-` ([html5rocks.com: Custom Elements](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use any name for elements in html5, and old browsers will just treat them as `div`s, there's nothing special about it being called `bootstrap`